# Two vectors $u,v$ from a prehilbert space are orthogonal if and only if... (proof)

Tags: inner-products, orthogonality

> Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a prehilbert space. Two vectors $u,v$ are
> orthogonal w.r.t. hermitic product if and only if
> \begin{equation*} 
>  \parallel \alpha u + \beta v \parallel^2 = \parallel \alpha u \parallel^2 + \parallel \beta v \parallel^2, \quad \quad \forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}. 
> \end{equation*}

Proof.

To  the right
\begin{equation*} 
 \parallel \alpha u + \beta v \parallel^2 = (\alpha u + \beta v \ | \ \alpha u + \beta v) = \parallel \alpha u \parallel^2 + \parallel \beta v \parallel^2 + \alpha^{\ast}\beta (u \ | \  v) + \alpha\beta^{\ast} (v \ | \  u)
\end{equation*}
If they are orthogonal then
\begin{equation*} 
 \parallel \alpha u + \beta v \parallel^2 = \parallel \alpha u \parallel^2 + \parallel \beta v \parallel^2 \quad \quad \forall \alpha , \beta \in \mathbb{C}
\end{equation*}
To the left. Similary we obtain the following expresion
\begin{equation*} 
 \alpha^{\ast}\beta (u \ | \  v) + \alpha\beta^{\ast} (v \ | \  u) = 0 \quad \quad \forall \alpha , \beta \in \mathbb{C}
\end{equation*}
If $\alpha, \beta =1$ then $\mathfrak{Re}[(u \ | \ v)] = 0$. How can I prove that $\mathfrak{Im}[(u \ | \ v)] = 0$, so they are orthogonals? (or another method)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: To get $\mathfrak{Re} (u | v) = 0$, you chose the parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in such a way that you can use the equation $z + z^* = 2\mathfrak{Re} z$. The similar equation $z - z^* = 2\mathfrak{Im} z$ will be helpful for the last part. Can you make a different choice for the parameters $\alpha, \beta$ so that this equation can be applied?

Comment: Yes, I knew that thanks anyway. But my initial question (maybe I wasn't clear enough) is that I couldn't manage to come up with that choise of parameters.

Comment: Maybe $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta = i$? Yes, Im sure is that!